# MSM displaying main site when going to second site's domain?

Tags: multi-site-manager

I've installed a new site using MSM but when I hit the domain it's showing the content from our original domain. I'm not sure where to look for this.

Comment: You'll need to post more information about the setup of your second site... Did you follow these instructions for setting up the second site? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html

Answer (score 1):

In your index.php file for the second site (or third or fourth...) there are $assign_to_config variables.

From the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html):

```
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'domain2_short_name';
$assign_to_config['cp_url']    = 'http://domain2.com/admin.php';
$assign_to_config['site_url']  = 'http://domain2.com';
```

All three should be set properly or it can default to the main site.